# Cloud Datastore metric baseline to be alerted

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, metrics, alerts, stable-baselines

In my company, there is a request to be alerted for the following metrics on a Cloud DataStore service configuration but they don't know which are the baselines for each of these metrics.

Do they have to be like a fixed count (ie: request_count > 100) or maybe an average.

```
api/request_count
index/write_count
entity/read_sizes
entity/write_sizes
```

I was checking free quota limits [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing#free_quota) but I'm not really sure which values can be the right ones to use for a baseline.

Comment: After you [enable Billing](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#enabling_billing_and_setting_a_spending_limit) you can [Edit your Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#managing_your_quota) as desired. If you are not sure which Quotas you should increase, please contact GCP support directly from your [Support portal](https://console.cloud.google.com/support)